# Удаление переменных окружения для конкретного процесса в Linux

Tags: linux, environment-variables

Где-то на просторах интернета видел (сейчас найти не могу) как в Linux можно ограничить доступ программе к общим/системным переменным окружения. ...и, пока пишу эти строки, вспомнил, что есть
`env -i имя_программы`
Но и это не все подчистую убирает. Остаются штуки четыре переменных, среди которых PATH и PWD. Их как-то можно убрать?

Comment: `env -i` убирает всё. Если вы там внутри запускаете какой-нибудь bash, то это он себе сам добавляет переменные.

Comment: Alexey, спасибо! Я именно на bash и проверял, а изнутри бинарника посмотреть руки пока не дошли. Помогли.